# Insert a row every given time else update previous row (Postgresql, PHP)

Tags: php, c++, apache, postgresql, upsert

I have a multiple devices (eleven to be specific) which sends information every second. This information in recieved in a apache server, parsed by a PHP script, stored in the database and finally displayed in a gui.
What I am doing right now is check if a row for teh current day exists, if it doesn't then create a new one, otherwise update it. 
The reason I do it like that is because I need to poll the information from the database and display it in a c++ application to make it look sort of real-time; If I was to create a row every time a device would send information, processing and reading the data would take a significant ammount of time as well as system resources (Memory, CPU, etc..) making the displaying of data not quite real-time.
I wrote a report generation tool which takes the information for every day (from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59) and put it in an excel spreadsheet.

My questions are basically:

- Is it posible to do the insertion/updating part directly in the database server or do I have to do the logic in the php script?
- Is there a better (more efficient) way to store the information without a decrease in performance in the display device?
- Regarding the report generation, if I want to sample intervals lets say starting from yesterday at 15:50:00 and ending today at 12:45:00 it cannot be done with my current data structure, so what do I need to consider in order to make a data structure which would allow me to create such queries.

The components I use:
   - Apache 2.4.4
   - PostgreSQL 9.2.3-2
   - PHP 5.4.13

Comment: You should give the exact version of the components used (in this case the version of postgres is very important).

Comment: @JakubKania Sorry, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendations - just store all the information, your devices are sending. With proper indexes and queries you can process and retrieve information from DB really fast.

For your questions:

Yes it is possible to build any logic you desire inside Postgres DB using SQL, PL/pgSQL, PL/PHP, PL/Java, PL/Py and many other languages built into Postgres.

As I said before - proper indexing can do magic.

If you cannot get desired query speed with full table - you can create a small table with 1 row for every device. And keep in this table last known values to show them in `sort of real-time`.

Comment: Do you know of any good resources about indexes? That particular topic is not one of my skills.

Comment: Thank you, I will read and try. I'll come back with some news afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

1) The technique is called upsert. In PG 9.1+ it can be done with wCTE (http://www.depesz.com/2011/03/16/waiting-for-9-1-writable-cte/)

2) If you really want it to be real-time you should be sending the data directly to the aplication, storing it in memory or plaintext file also will be faster if you only care about the last few values. But PG does have Listen/notify channels so probabably your lag will be just 100-200 mili and that shouldn't be much taken you're only displaying it.

Comment: I tried using notify channels, they work but I got stuck in the point where every device sends different information so the processing is also different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overestimating the memory system requirements given the process you have described. Adding a row of data every second (or 11 per second) is not a hog of resources. In fact it is likely more time consuming to UPDATE vs ADD a new row. Also, if you add a TIMESTAMP to your table, sort operations are lightning fast. Just add some garbage collection handling as a CRON job (deletion of old data) once a day or so and you are golden.

However to answer your questions:

> Is it posible to do the insertion/updating part directly in the database server or do I >have to do the logic in the php script?

Writing logic from with the Database engine is usually not very straight forward. To keep it simple stick with the logic in the php script. UPDATE (or) INSERT INTO table SET var1='assignment1', var2='assignment2' (WHERE id = 'checkedID')

> Is there a better (more efficient) way to store the information without a decrease in >performance in the display device?

It's hard to answer because you haven't described the display device connectivity. There are more efficient ways to do the process however none that have locking mechanisms required for such frequent updating.

> Regarding the report generation, if I want to sample intervals lets say starting from >yesterday at 15:50:00 and ending today at 12:45:00 it cannot be done with my current data >structure, so what do I need to consider in order to make a data structure which would >allow me to create such queries.

You could use the a TIMESTAMP variable type. This would include DATE and TIME of the UPDATE operation. Then it's just a simple WHERE clause using DATE functions within the database query.

Comment: When the application starts it will get a list of devices, then it then starts a timer and based on the list will call a partucular method for each device, when finished reading the information, will start the process again.

Comment: Is the application simply a local (For your eyes only) or multiple users style?

Comment: It is both local and shared.